# How do I keep a pattern overlay layer effect from moving around separately when animating?

Tags: after-effects, animation, effects

How do I keep a pattern overlay layer effect from moving around separately when I do a rotation of the object the effect is applied to in After Effects? I created this composition in Photoshop and imported it into After Effects. It is almost correct except that the scratched metal pattern isn't following the rotation of the gear shape. It moves in a different way. See example here: https://cl.ly/3x2L2P2S2X3K Thank you.

Comment: Link is broken. Flagged for closing as "needs clarification".

Answer (score 1):

Delete any motion or rotation keyframes in the overlay layer. Now line it up with the gear layer as you want, then make the gear layer the parent for the pattern layer.

To set a layer's parent you need to have the parent column visible in the timeline window. If it's not visible, right-click the column headings and choose it from the list. In the parent column you can then use the drop down to select the layer's parent or drag the pick-whip (the little spiral widget) to the chosen layer.

Comment: Thanks @stib I have located the parent column but there are no options for parenting the gear with its pattern overlay because it is a layer style. See here https://cl.ly/2R3J062Z3d0c Maybe this isn't the best way to be setup for this transformation. Anyway, parenting with the later above doesn't solve the problem. It looks the same as in the example render.

Comment: Oh, ok, probably the best thing to do would be to precomp the gear layer (**Layer>Pre-Compose**) before you parent the precomp to its parent.